# Jquery not working on mobile browser

Tags: jquery, mobile, browser-compatibility

I have a following jquery code that runs fine on desktop but doesn't run on mobile browser on my wordpress website. It attaches a parameter on ajax based search box but not doing on mobile browsers. Any idea why?

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 


    $("input.orig").mouseout(function() {

    var stt = $(this).val();        


setTimeout(function() { 
    $("a.asp_res_url").each(function() {        
   var $this = $(this);       
   var _href = $this.attr("href"); 
   var _href2 = $this.attr("href").split('?')[0];
    $this.attr("href", _href2 + '?s='+stt);
        
    
});
}, 0);  
    
});
    
});
    
</script>
```